# How to compose multiple React createPortal with same properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have a react app with multiple modals that have similar functionality. How can I extract a component to remove the redundant code?

```
function App() {
  const [viewMode, setViewMode] = useState("default")

  const handleCancel = () => setViewMode("default");
  const handleSave = () => {
    setViewMode("default");
    reloadData();
  };

  return (
    <>
      {viewMode === "modal1" && createPortal(<Modal1 onCancel={handleCancel} onSave={handleSave} additionalDifferentProp="foo" />, document.body)}
      {viewMode === "modal2" && createPortal(<Modal2 onCancel={handleCancel} onSave={handleSave} additionalDifferentProp2="bar" />, document.body)}
    </>
  )
}
```

I can move the createPortal handling into a new component that handles the switching logic but I do not have a solution how to remove pass `handleCancel` and `handleSave` as default properties to children.

```
<PortalView
  viewMode={viewMode}
  views={{
    modal1: <Modal1 onCancel={handleCancel} onSave={handleSave} additionalDifferentProp="foo"/>,
    modal2: <Modal2 onCancel={handleCancel} onSave={handleSave} additionalDifferentProp2="bar"/>,
  }}
/>
```

Am I over complicating things? The real app uses multiple modals with multiple additional properties. Should I look at render props or React.Children or React.cloneElement? All of these seem to be discouraged in modern react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the complete wrong approach a portal should be close to the thing triggering it (e.g. a button) so you don't need something like viewMode. A different approach could also be to use a real frontend router as that would also cover those funcitonalities.